# Can NextAuth middleware work to protect pages when using NextJS 14 and the app router?

Tags: amazon-cognito, next.js13, next-auth, app-router

I've tried all sorts of things but either the server produces errors that the code can't run in the middle ware for one reason or another or the middle ware fails to detect when the request has a valid session.  In some instances the server logs have this joyous uselessness (like when I try to call nextauth getServerSession, which I presume just won't work in middleware - thanks nextauth for not documenting that) :)

```
⨯ node_modules/oidc-token-hash/lib/shake256.js (3:0) @ <unknown>
```

I know my serverside pages can call nextauth's getServerSession().  I tried using the built in middleware with nextauth and that fails to notice a valid session (it doesn't even see a token).  It appears that nextauth is kinda just broken in this area but I'd be thrilled to see a working example of nextauth middle ware (I"m yusing with with AWS Cogito but suspect the issue exists in other configs).  The code below for example never sees a token.

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import authOptions from './app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/authOptions';
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";

export default withAuth(
    function middleware(req) {
        console.log(req);
        console.log(req.nextauth.token)
    }, {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => { console.log("Token", token) ; return !!token} ,
    },
  })


// Tried this and it didn't work either - and many other incantations that don't work
// import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
// import authOptions from './app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/authOptions';

// export default NextAuth(authOptions).auth;


export const config = { matcher: ["/creator/:path*"] }
```

Below is my config:

```
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CognitoIdentityServiceProvider from "next-auth/providers/cognito"

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
            clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET!,
            issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER!
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({user, token, account, profile}) {
            // console.log("Profile", profile)
            // console.log('Token', token)
            // console.log('Account', account)

            // Initial sign in
            if (user && account && profile) {
                token.sub = profile.sub; // Persist the 'sub' from the profile
            }
            // console.log("Token sub", token.sub)
            return token;
        },
    
        async session({session, token}) {
            // console.log("session callback: Token", token)

            session.user.sub = token.sub; // Make 'sub' available on the session object
            // console.log("Session user sub", session.user.sub)

            return session;
        },
    },
    // events: {
    //     signOut: async (message) => {   
    //       console.log('User signed out', message);
    //     },
    // },
}

export default authOptions;
```

Answer (score 0):

No `getServerSession` from `next-auth` v4, will not run on NextJS 13.4 / 14 app router middleware.  The problem is that getServerSession is designed to run on a server with a NodeJS runtime but the app router's middleware runs on `edge` runtime which strictly supports only Web API.

There is a next-auth v5 currently in Beta where they have rearchitected the entire library to be agnostic, to run on any runtime; server, edge or client.

You can see in the v5 upgrade docs (link below) that there was not previous support for edge runtime, and that the new agnostic solution is to replace `getServerSession` with `auth`.

https://authjs.dev/guides/upgrade-to-v5#authenticating-server-side